# Windows 10 - File Explorer uses up CPU to refresh a folder being modified by other programs

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems

So I have encountered this problem and successfully recreated it numerous times.

The problem is simple: whenever using any software other than explorer, to delete/move/copy/rename... contents of a any folder, if that folder is opened in explorer while the operation is running, explorer will instantly use up 100% CPU to refresh the folder, and slow down the operation, and cause my computer to become very irresponsive(not freezed), and keep doing so until either the operation has ended or the folder is closed in explorer...

So is this the normal behavior of Windows? Is this a bug? How can I fix(or improve) this? I am using Windows 10 20H2 x64 if that helps.

Edit: I can confirm there are no system file corruptions, I have run DISM and SFC numerous times and they can't fix this issue, they fail to detect any problem.
Also I had just reinstalled Windows very recently. I have also run many hard disk utilities to check if hard drives have any bad sectors, and there is none. And I have also run chkdsk numerous times and no filesystem corruptions. So they are not the case.

Example: Try this in PowerShell, it should recreate the problem described, use at your own risk.

```
$test=[string]"C:\test"+$(get-random)
md $test
explorer $test
taskmgr
0..10000 | % {ni "${test}\${_}.txt"|out-null}
(gci $test).fullname | %{ri $_}
rd $test
```

Screenshot:[image]

P.S. If it really succeeded recreating the problem described, just restart explorer, and let PowerShell do its job, don't close PowerShell before it completes deletion, because explorer deletion speed is lower than PowerShell(maybe)(because explorer will compute number of files and ETA before deletion, the script finds one and deletes one)

Edit:

I use PowerShell 7.1 and

```
gci $test | %{ri $_}
```

works fine, but it might not work on lower versions of PowerShell, So I generalized it, now lower versions of powershell can find the paths.

Proof:

[image]

If the files were not deleted first, removing the folder will cause it prompt the warning Recurse parameter not specified and asking for confirmation.

Context Menus:

Desktop:

[image]

Explorer(not "This PC"):

[image]

"This PC"

[image]

"New"

[image]

My hard drives are Hard Disk Devices, I guess you people are all using Solid State Drives? You are so rich...

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Perhaps someone can trace this for you with Process Explorer and using that PS logic to try to figure out what is being done behind the scenes to cause this behavior with File Explorer. There should be some way of determining what's sucking up the CPU during these operations.

Comment: Do you have network shares mounted/mapped, as that can cause the issue experienced, as can third party context menu items _(search on here for how to check)_

Comment: @JW0914, I don't know what network shares is, though it seems to be related to servers, I am not running a server and I don't share files, I am not in a homegroup, as for context menu items, I disabled most of them, I will look into it.

Comment: The script does not work. It creates a folder named `C:\test987554766` with 10000 files, then fails with many messages like  `ri : Cannot find path 'C:\Temp\265.txt' because it does not exist.` until it stops. No excessive CPU utilization.

Comment: Yes, the post is too hard to answer in its current form: The script does not demonstrate the problem and the screenshots are not helping.

Comment: The provided script does not cause the same issue on my Windows 10 PC. This computer has a very old CPU, so doubt it's a performance issue. What type of hard drive are you using? I have had similar issues in the past with hard drives that are failing.

Comment: @harrymc I think the question is clear and answerable, and the script is actually very useful for attempting to reproduce the problem. I didn't have any issues running it, I just didn't get the same high CPU usage from explorer, which does in fact narrow it down to something specific with the OP's setup.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but have you tried enabling "launch folder windows in a separate process"?

Comment: I had always set that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem on a specific folder with Windows Explorer. I disabled thumbnails to avoid high cpu usage. Maybe it helps you, [How to disable thumbnails on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-thumbnails-windows-10)

Comment: Congratulations! You got lucky, because someone has upvoted your answer, though it didn't solve my problem, the website will automatically award the bounty to you anyways, and it seems the answer I had waited for will never come...So I will upvote your answer and accept it.

Comment: Sorry that the solution didn't work. The score doesn't matter. I hope the problem has a valid reason.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix(or improve) this?

The official way of reporting issues with Windows is to use their "Feedback Hub" app, included with Windows 10:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/feedback-hub/9nblggh4r32n

[image: Feedback Hub]

This then relies on upvotes and such, like you'd expect to find with most crowdsourced feedback.

This is a replacement of the now-defunct http://connect.microsoft.com/ that attempted to do the same thing.

Unfortunately, collecting issue reports and acting on them do not go hand in hand.  Well documented, easily reproducible bugs (like not being able to undo the actions taken by using a Quick Step action in Outlook) go for years and versions of Windows just collecting upvotes and dust.

> So is this the normal behavior of Windows? Is this a bug?

It doesn't sound unreasonable that two applications working on the same dataset at the same time would run into record locks and so forth that either the system or the software would have to overcome, and that CPU usage would get out of hand.  Especially when it comes to Windows File Explorer showing the contents of a directory.  Windows 7/8/Vista was horrible at refreshing the directory in the first place, even without something in the background changing the contents it's meant to display.  Windows 10 is much better, but still not great.  So, is it normal?  Yes.  Is it a bug?  Maybe.

Report the issue, and find a way around what you're trying to accomplish.